# QGIS form control to show multiple selection data

Tags: qgis

I need to show labels for coded values recorded in one single field, i.e.:

```
Crops Field
Row 1: 1 2 3
Row 2: 1 3
Row 3: 1 4

Codes: 
1 - Maize
2 - Beans
3 - Sugar Cane
4 - Others
```

I want to show the labels for this data within a QGIS form, when a user clicks for information, is this possible, I can´t find an appropriate controller.

Comment: I think you can create a custom function for this. I don't know how to code the whole thing, so here's some pseudocode: Create an empty array. `case when regexp_match("Crops Field", '1') then` append 'Maize' to the array. Repeat for all crop values.

Comment: Or have a look at the Value Relation field edit widget, which allows multiple selections. Maybe you can set that up to interpret your data.

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on your layer and go to to properties. From here select the attributes option and you'll see a 'fields' drop down with your fields listed below. Click on your fields with the codes and change the widget type to 'value map'. Within here you can now create your code with the description. In my example below code 1 shows as the description hello when you click the information tool.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Chris thanks for the idea, but this field has many codes (as much as multiple selections a user selected), i.e it could have a "1" for Hello, then it could have a "1 2" for "Hello" and "Carlos" at the same time, and so on. So I need to be able to show values that are togheter "mixed" in a single field, only separated by a space.